# Making a sum of numericupdown values from a group box

Tags: c#

For a project I need to take the values from several `NumericUpDown`s (amount of items you want to order from a specific item) which are placed in a group box. Then I need to use this sum to get the right price.
one scoop of ice cream = 2,10 EUR, two scoops of ice cream = 3,80 EUR and three scoops of ice cream = 5,10 EUR.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    double callories = 0;
    double price = 0;
    string text = "";

    foreach (Control x in grpTypesOfIcecream.Controls)
    {
        int sum1 = 0;

        if (x is NumericUpDown)
        {
            int number = (int)((NumericUpDown)x).Value;                    

            sum1 += number;
            callories += (133 * sum1);

            if (sum1 == 1)
            {
                price += 2.1;
                text += "one scoop of ice";
            }
            else if (sum1 == 2)
            {
                price += 3.8;
                text += "two scoops of ice";
            }
            else if (sum1 == 3)
            {
                price += 5.1;
                text += "three scoops of ice";
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I start my program and a `NumericUpDown` value is 2 I do get the price of 3.8 EUR, but when I take 2 `NumericUpDown`s which both have value 1 it doesn't make a sum and my outcome is 4.2 EUR (2.1 + 2.1).

Whenever I take 2 `NumericUpDown`s with both value 1 it should give me a price of 3.8 EUR, not 4.2...

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `int sum1 = 0;` needs to be inside foreach?

Comment: When clicking on 'voeg toe' the values have to go to 'Winkelkarretje" https://gyazo.com/6304a0f4a0501753fe94517811ea17fd

Comment: Hi Dries,  It looks like the problem is because your sum1 variable that you are using to accumulate your sum is declared inside the loop, so every time it iterates through the loop, it is initialized to zero losing the previous value.  Move that declaration outside the loop.

Comment: @FredFerenczhalmy how could I fix this? I'm very new to coding is it possible to send me and example code?

Answer (score 0):

To fix just move the int sum1 = 0 to just before the foreach loop.  Having it inside the loop makes it a new instance of that variable each iteration of the foreach loop, which will not work if you want to keep a running total.  Having it outside the loop declares  and initializes it only once, so each time through the loop, the previous value will still be there for you to add to it.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    double callories = 0;
    double price = 0;
    string text = "";
    int sum1 = 0;

    foreach (Control x in grpTypesOfIcecream.Controls)
    {

        if (x is NumericUpDown)
        {
            int number = (int)((NumericUpDown)x).Value;


                sum1 += number;
                callories += (133 * sum1);

                if (sum1 == 1)
                {
                    price += 2.1;
                    text += "one scoop of ice";
                }
                else if (sum1 == 2)
                {
                    price += 3.8;
                    text += "two scoops of ice";
                }
                else if (sum1 == 3)
                {
                    price += 5.1;
                    text += "three scoops of ice";
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever I do this, the bottom numericupdown (red in picture) works as it should but the numricupdown above that one (pink) gives double the value? https://gyazo.com/048ed25b315a3de2184357a71e25b61b (both values of the numericupdown were 2)

Comment: You'll need to be a little more clear about what are your inputs, and what is the expected behavior for those inputs.  I can't tell what your expected output is based on your comments above.  Please be specific about what your expected result should be for a given input.

Comment: I've put the If and else if's for the prices outside of the loop, after the foreach and it worked out as it should've, thanks for the help and my apologies if I was unclear about what I was in need of help with

Comment: No problem on the details - the more details you provide the easier it is for anyone to help.  Glad to hear you got it working.